# Golang pq: syntax error when executing sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, revel

Using `revel`, `golang 1.1.2`, `gorp`, `postgres 9.3.2` on `heroku`

Following `robfig`'s List [booking example](https://github.com/robfig/revel/blob/master/samples/booking/app/controllers/hotels.go)

```
func (c App) ViewPosts(page int) revel.Result {
    if page == 0 {
        page = 1
    }
    var posts []*models.Post
    size := 10
    posts = loadPosts(c.Txn.Select(models.Post{},
        `select * from posts offset ? limit ?`, (page-1)*size, size)) // error here
    return c.RenderJson(posts)
}
```

Not sure why I'm getting `pq: syntax error at or near "limit"`. I'm assuming the combined query is wrong. Why does the query not end up being something like `select * from posts offset 0 limit 10`, which I've tested to run on postgres. Where am I messing up?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not familiar with postgres, but I found this [issue](https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/174). I think you should use it like in the [godoc](http://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq)

**Example in godoc**

```
age := 21
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE age = $1", age)
```

(Replace "?" with "$n")

**Your code**

```
func (c App) ViewPosts(page int) revel.Result {
if page == 0 {
    page = 1
}
var posts []*models.Post
size := 10
posts = loadPosts(c.Txn.Select(models.Post{},
    `select * from posts offset $1 limit $2`, (page-1)*size, size))
return c.RenderJson(posts)
}
```

Comment: If anyone else stumbles across this, I seen it with Gorm in Golang when using the `.Limit()`.  This was because I had left a `;` at the end of my query, so Gorm adding a limit after the fact was problematic.